# Unity animation out of sync when origin is moving

Tags: unity, c#, animation

This is the animation code which is running a cube on animation points:

```
public void Start()
{
    AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
    clip.name = "Track1";
    clip.legacy = true;

    List<Keyframe> keyX = new List<Keyframe>();
    List<Keyframe> keyY = new List<Keyframe>();
    List<Keyframe> keyZ = new List<Keyframe>();

    List<Keyframe> keyXRot = new List<Keyframe>();
    List<Keyframe> keyYRot = new List<Keyframe>();
    List<Keyframe> keyZRot = new List<Keyframe>();
    float timer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Track1.Count; i++)
    {
        //Vector3 pointPos = Track1[i].gameObject.transform.localPosition;
        //Vector3 pointRot = Track1[i].gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles;

        Vector3 pointPos = Track1[i].gameObject.transform.position;
        Vector3 pointRot = Track1[i].gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles;
        keyX.Add(new Keyframe(timer, pointPos.x, 0,0,0,0));
        keyY.Add(new Keyframe(timer, pointPos.y, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        keyZ.Add(new Keyframe(timer, pointPos.z, 0, 0, 0, 0));

        keyXRot.Add(new Keyframe(timer, pointRot.x, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        keyYRot.Add(new Keyframe(timer, pointRot.y, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        keyZRot.Add(new Keyframe(timer, pointRot.z, 0, 0, 0, 0));

        timer += 1f;

    }

    AnimationCurve curveX = new AnimationCurve(keyX.ToArray());
    AnimationCurve curveY = new AnimationCurve(keyY.ToArray());
    AnimationCurve curveZ = new AnimationCurve(keyZ.ToArray());

    AnimationCurve curveX_Rot = new AnimationCurve(keyXRot.ToArray());
    AnimationCurve curveY_Rot = new AnimationCurve(keyYRot.ToArray());
    AnimationCurve curveZ_Rot = new AnimationCurve(keyZRot.ToArray());

    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", curveX);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.y", curveY);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.z", curveZ);

    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localEulerAngles.x", curveX_Rot);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localEulerAngles.y", curveY_Rot);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localEulerAngles.z", curveZ_Rot);

    clip.wrapMode = WrapMode.Loop;

    Animation anim = GetComponent<Animation>();

    // now animate the GameObject
    anim.AddClip(clip, clip.name);

    //anim.clip.wrapMode = WrapMode.Loop;
    anim.Play(clip.name);
}
```

This is working fine as long as I don't move my overall environment. Currently I have an origin that contains all the models and this animation.

The problem is that if I move the origin, then the animation is no longer in sync with my points.

I try to use local position for animation but it is even out of sync when the origin is at zero.

Comment: When does your origin move? If it's changing position continuously, in a way you can't predict in advance, then a baked animation clip won't be able to compensate for that motion. But if it's just placed at a non-zero position and doesn't "move" over time, then we can transform world coordinates into its local space when adding them to the animation curve.

Comment: Whenever my player goes behind 2000 distance from the 0 positions then, it re shifts its position near the 0 positions.

Comment: it sounds like you're using a floating origin to help keep floating point precision close to the player. But using an animation curve authored in global coordinates will defeat this purpose. If the animated position was more than 2000 units from the player, you only have that level of precision in the animated position. Later subtracting 2000 to bring it closer does not bring that precision back. So after enough of these shifts you'll start seeing choppy and inaccurate movement, even for content "close to the origin" because it"s been authored in a space far from thr origin.

Comment: Well, I complete didn't understand your meaning. But yes I am using floating origin. And the reason to use floating origin, my animation starts jerking after it goes far away from 2000 in position. In order to control this choppy jerk or spatial jitter effect I have added a floating origin. But it brings up the issue which I have posted in this question.

Comment: So if this animation is meant to cross between multiple 2k "chunks" of your world, you'll need a new plan — I'd recommend editing your question to explain what this animation represents for tips on that. If this animation is always fully contained in one such chunk, then we can author it in its nearest chunk's space and only ever incur reshifting precision loss when it's far away (and thus small on screen where errors aren't noticeable).